# Erro Flutter - @pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace") external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dropdown

I'm new to Flutter and I'm running my project and I create two dropdown entries, where the operation and methods will be below

```
class _StateDataRegistration extends State<RegistrationData> {
    
     List lsStates = [];
    

    _StateDataRegistration () {
        _listStates();
    }

    _listStates() {
        API._listStates().then((response) {
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            setState(() {
              lsStates = jsonDecode(response.body);
            });
          }
       });
    }


    _listaMunicipios(String siglaEstado) {
    _municipioController = 0;
    lsMunicipios = [];
    loadingMunicipio = true;

    API.listaCidades(siglaEstado).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          lsMunicipios = jsonResponse.map<Municipio>((json) => Municipio.fromJson(json)).toList();
        });
      }
      loadingMunicipio = false;
    });
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24, horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32, bottom: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      DropdownButtonFormField(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value:
                            (_estadoController != 0) ? _estadoController : null,
                        items: lsStates
                            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                  child: Text(e['nome']),
                                  value: int.parse(e['id'].toString()),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                        onTap: () =>
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            int estado_id = int.parse(value.toString());
                            final estadoSelec = lsEstados
                                .where((element) => element['id'] == estado_id)
                                .toList();

                            _estadoController = estado_id;
                            _listaMunicipios(estadoSelec[0]['sigla']);
                          });
                        },
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Escolha seu Estado'),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value == 0) {
                            return "O estado é obrigatório";
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      DropdownButtonFormField(
                        icon: (loadingMunicipio)
                            ? SizedBox(
                                width: 16,
                                height: 16,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  strokeWidth: 2,
                                ),
                              )
                            : null,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value: (_municipioController != 0)
                            ? _municipioController
                            : null,
                        items: lsMunicipios
                            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                  child: Text(e.municipio),
                                  value: int.parse(e.id.toString()),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                        onTap: () =>
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _municipioController = int.parse(value.toString());
                          });
                        },
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Escolha seu Município'),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value == 0) {
                            return "O município é obrigatório";
                          }
                        },
                      ),

}
```

But when running, it was supposed to show me the list of cities based on the acronym Estado, but when I run setState, it opens a tab with an error:

```
@patch
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace")
  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

I've looked for the solution but I can't find it at all!

Comment: What is the actual error?  You also need to examine the stack trace to see what called `Error.throwWithStackTrace` (or what called that, and so on) to see what the root cause is.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and wrapped it in a Container to fix it.
Try wrapping DropdownButtonFormField with a SizedBox or Container and add width and height properties like this:

```
Container(
    height:50,
    width:100,
    child:DropdownButtonFormField(),
  ),
```

Hope it works!!